# How to specify a tab in a postgres front-end COPY

Tags: postgresql, csv

I would like to use the psql "\copy" command to pull data from a tab-delimited file into Postgres.  I'm using this command:

```
\copy cm_state from 'state.data' with delimiter '\t' null as ;
```

But I'm getting this warning (the table actually loads fine):

```
WARNING:  nonstandard use of escape in a string literal
LINE 1: COPY cm_state FROM STDIN DELIMITER '\t' NULL AS ';'
HINT:  Use the escape string syntax for escapes, e.g., E'\r\n'.
```

How do I specify a tab if '\t' is not correct?

Comment: Try what the error message suggests: `\copy cm_state from 'state.data' with delimiter E'\t' null as ';'`

Comment: E begins an escape sequence. Think of E much like you would a double quoted string in C. E'\t' == "\t".

Answer (score 228, accepted):

Use `E'\t'` to tell postgresql there may be escaped characters in there:

```
\copy cm_state from 'state.data' with delimiter E'\t' null as ';'
```

Comment: Thanks! This also solved the less informative error `COPY delimiter must be a single one-byte character` for me. Adding it here so search engines can pick up on it.

Comment: This should be another answer with error message. Just so that the search engines pick it up :)

Answer (score 7):

you can do this `copy cm_state from stdin with (format 'text')`

Comment: the default delimiter for text file is a tab.. I have used this and it works .. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html

Comment: This helps when you want to put the command in a shell script -- `$$\t$$` doesn't seem to work, oddly.

Comment: This works for data generated by `pg_dump` without other options specified.

Comment: use `\COPY tabname(col1, col2) FROM 'in.csv' with (FORMAT text, HEADER)` if csv column split by \t & have header line
//header line just skip, columns order from sql.

Answer (score 3):

Thx this E'\t' formatting. Escaping character works when importing tab separated (TSV) data files, and headers not only in CSV.

This way I have successful imported a TSV, but only with DELIMITER option as follows in this psql (contained excluded header)

```
\COPY mytable FROM 'mydata.tsv' DELIMITER E'\t' CSV HEADER;
```