# Postgresql : Search field contain tab character. (With LIKE)

Tags: postgresql

I'm searching how to check if any field contains the TAB character.

after read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113115/how-do-i-specify-a-tab-in-a-postgres-front-end-copy), I tried to use this command :

```
SELECT id FROM account WHERE description LIKE '%\t%';
```

But it returns me all fields that contain the 't' character.

Do you have any solution to represent the TAB character ?

Comment: or you can use hex value: 0x09 :D...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In SQL there is no "escaping" of characters like `\t`. You can use the `chr()` function for this:

```
select id
from account
where description LIKE '%'||chr(9)||'%'
```

I prefer the `strpos` function in this case, because I think it makes the intention clearer

```
select id
from account
where strpos(description, chr(9)) > 0
```

Answer (score 6):

you have to use a literal tab chacater,

```
 SELECT id FROM account WHERE description LIKE '%   %';
```

In psql type ctrl-V and then TAB to enter a tab. in other environments there are other ways to enter literal tabs.

Alternatively you can use escape string syntax: `e'%\t%'`,  or octal escape `e'%\011%'`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm very late to this party, but having looked into this today, I've found you can also use regular expression.

```
SELECT id FROM account WHERE description ~ '\t';
```

Comment: Indeed you can, postgresql internally converts the LIKE expression to regex. the question asked for a solution using LIKE but the accepted answer uses a different method.

Comment: Having a literal tab in the query is dangerous if you have other coders who may open the file and convert tabs to spaces.