# Import CSV data with delimiter tabulation in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, csv, delimiter

I have a csv file with data like "44444     521     hello".
Scapes here are "Tabulations".

I want to import csv data in a table named "TEST1" so i did this :

```
\copy TEST(attribut1,attribut2,attribut3) FROM '/mnt/c/Users/user1/Desktop/data/test1.csv' WITH DELIMITER E'\t' CSV HEADER;
```

attribut1 = integer. attribut2 = integer. attribut3 = varchar(20).

And it said :

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "44444     521     hello"
>   CONTEXT:  COPY test1, line 2, column attribut1: "4444444     521
>   hello"

Thanks for your time.

**EDIT** :

Here is a screenshot of the file in a hex editor : [image]

Comment: Seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113115/how-to-specify-a-tab-in-a-postgres-front-end-copy ? Open your file in a hex editor, take a screenshot and post it, please

Comment: yes @CaiusJard , i have ever seen this page. But it doesn't work

Comment: Is data in quotes like that? If so, Postgres is rightfully considering them one value where tabs are part of the string.

Comment: How's that screenshot of your file, open in a hex editor, coming along?

Comment: I have edited my post @CaiusJard

Comment: Parfait was right

Comment: @CaiusJard so what i have to  change in my query ? What i have to change about the E'\t' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes because you're specifying CSV, which activates postgres' csv import rules. Your file isn't being treated as tab separated; it has `"` quotes at the start and end of each line which in CSV mode mean "start of data"/"end of data", so each line is treated as a single field, the tabs inside are treated as data, not delimiters

Either import it in text mode (don't specify CSV) or import it in CSV mode but specify a different quote char (a char that isn't present in the file, 1) to stop `"` being treated as quote and 2) so no other character can be treated as quote)

In either case you'll have to strip the quote `"` chars out post process - I don't think you can manipulate the data on the fly as it is copied so you'll have to load it into a staging table first, (all varchar) then strip the quotes and load it into your real table (`REPLACE(data, '"', '')::int`)

Or, you could text editor your file and remove the `"` chars from it before you give it to postgres